# How can I merge rows if a column data is same and change a value of another specific column on merged column efficiently in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to merge rows if value of certain column are same. I have been using groupby first and replace the data the value of column based on specific condition. I was wondering if there is a better option to do what I am trying to do.

This is what I have been doing

```
data={'Name': {0: 'Sam', 1: 'Amy', 2: 'Cat', 3: 'Sam', 4: 'Kathy'},
 'Subject1': {0: 'Math', 1: 'Science', 2: 'Art', 3: np.nan, 4: 'Science'},
 'Subject2': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: 'English', 4: np.nan},
 'Result': {0: 'Pass', 1: 'Pass', 2: 'Fail', 3: 'TBD', 4: 'Pass'}}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df.groupby('Name').agg({
 'Subject1': 'first',
 'Subject2': 'first',
 'Result': ', '.join}).reset_index()

df['Result']=df['Result'].apply(lambda x: 'RESULT_FAILED' if x=='Pass, TBD'  else x )
```

Starting: df looks like:

```
    Name    Subject1    Subject2    Result
0   Sam     Math    NaN     Pass
1   Amy     Science     NaN     Pass
2   Cat     Art     NaN     Fail
3   Sam     NaN     English     TBD
4   Kathy   Science     NaN     Pass
```

Final result I want  is :

```
    Name    Subject1    Subject2    Result
0   Amy     Science     NaN     Pass
1   Cat     Art     NaN     Fail
2   Kathy   Science     NaN     Pass
3   Sam     Math    English     RESULT_FAILED
```

I believe this might not be a good solution if there are more than 100 columns. I will have to manually change the dictionary for aggregation.

I tried using : 
`df.groupby('Name')['Result'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()` but I only get 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample indicates each unique name having single non-NaN `SubjectX` value. I.e. each `SubjectX` has only one single non-NaN value for duplicate `Name`. You may try this way

```
import numpy as np

df_final = (df.fillna('').groupby('Name', as_index=False).agg(''.join)
                         .replace({'':np.nan, 'PassTBD': 'RESULT_FAILED'}))

Out[16]:
    Name Subject1 Subject2         Result
0    Amy  Science      NaN           Pass
1    Cat      Art      NaN           Fail
2  Kathy  Science      NaN           Pass
3    Sam     Math  English  RESULT_FAILED
```

Comment: If I want  all column to join and 1 column to perform something else, is it possible to do with with your method?

Comment: In that case, you need to use dictionary of aggfunc. Don't construct dictionary manually for each `column: aggfunc` as in your code. Use dictionary comprehension with `if` condition to handle the aggfunc for that 1 column.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I will play around with aggfunc